# timer in java with threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I am using the code below to open a frame-1 every x time but when i go to an other frame and back the timer reset itself causing a second frame-1 to show up 
which is problematic since I only need 1 at a time tried to use `isvisbile()` but did not work also.

Here is the code:

```
 int timerTimeInMilliSeconds2 = 30000;
    javax.swing.Timer timer2 = new javax.swing.Timer(timerTimeInMilliSeconds2, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Pop p=new Pop();
            p.setVisible(true);
            new Thread(){
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                       try {
                              Thread.sleep(5000); // time after which pop up will be disappeared.
                              p.dispose();
                       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                              e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                  };
            }.start();

        }
    });
    timer2.start();
```

Comment: your question line "back the timer reset it self causing a second frame-1 to show up wish is emblematic " is bit unclear. can you give more explanation on this to better understand your problem?

Comment: frame-1 is the pop up windows and frame-0 is my main 
i want frame-1 to open every x second wish i did in the code 
however every time i go from frame-0 to frame-x the timer reset and cause multiple frame-1 to pop up
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the `Pop p` object as a local variable inside your method having it as a member of your class. When `actionPerformed` triggers check whether it is null (a better name that `p` would be a good idea too) and only create the window if it is.

Rather than creating a thread to dispose the window after 5 seconds you should use another `Timer` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is little bit uncleared. As what I can understood, you need to create `Pop p` as a member variable of your defined class instead of local variable of method `actionPerformed` so that you can check before triggering it weather the object is `null` or not.